# How to fix AppHarbor : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: EndpointHost.Config

Tags: servicestack, appharbor

I deploy my ServiceStack to AppHarbor. On local, my ServiceStack work well. On AppHarbor build success but when i run http://cerp.apphb.com/api it has error

```
Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: EndpointHost.Config
```

How to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
diff --git a/src/CloudErp/Web.config b/src/CloudErp/Web.config
index 7c971ea..94f71a8 100644
--- a/src/CloudErp/Web.config
+++ b/src/CloudErp/Web.config
@@ -28,6 +28,7 @@
   <!-- ServiceStack: CustomPath /api -->
   <location path="api">
     <system.web>
+      <customErrors mode="Off" />
       <httpHandlers>
         <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
       </httpHandlers>
@@ -42,7 +43,7 @@
     </system.webServer>
   </location>
   <system.web>
-    <compilation debug="true" />
+    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
     <!--
       The <authentication> section enables configuration 
       of the security authentication mode used by 
@@ -70,6 +71,7 @@
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
+    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   </system.webServer>
   <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
```

And It worked now

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information, like how and where you're initializing your AppHost, e.g

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

One reason why this could happen is that your AppHost was not initialized correctly like when an exception was thrown on Startup. You'd need to refer to the error logs to see what the issue was.

Comment: Yes, my Application_Start like you. On localhost ServiceStack run well, but it has error on AppHarbor.

Comment: @TuanHoangAnh Right, and what I'm saying is that you need to find out what the error is. You need to check your error logs or add your own diagnostics as no-one can tell you what the error is from the outside.